# Computing a few eigenvalues of large sparse nonsymmetric matrix without LU factorisation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to find a few targeted eigenvalues of a large sparse (N=1e6,nnz=4e6) non-symmetric matrix.  Currently I'm using MATLAB's 'eigs' function with the 'sigma' option and this uses the Shifted Inverse method with Arnoldi iterations.  The problem is that I'm running out of memory with the LU matrix factorisation, even with 32GB of RAM.  I'm also trying incomplete LU factorisations as preconditioners to iterative solvers (bicg), which seem to work, but are very slow.  I can do the iterative solve without a preconditioner, but this is even slower.

Is there any software or methods that can accomplish this task without matrix factorisations?  Any other suggestions/strategies would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that it's not much about the efficiency of the eigensolver (which is [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/)), but about the linear solver used for the "inverse iteration". Then it depends on the matrix and on the problem it comes from. But no good recommendation can be made based solely on the matrix size and the number of nonzeros.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've actually had some success with the Jacobi-Davidson method (more specifically http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~vorst102/JDQR.html), which seems to be designed specifically for applications where the factorisation for a direct linear solve is too expensive.